# How and where to define a partial helper module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I want to split my helpers in different modules (and files), but I found some problems which I got around with the following solution:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  include ApplicationContainer
  # ...
end

# app/helpers/partials/application_container.rb
module ApplicationContainer
  # ...
end
```

In particular at the beginning I was looking to have a file `/app/helpers/_application_container_helper.rb` that gave me `uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::ApplicationContainer` (and different other errors playing around it), but right now I'm not even sure that makes sense.
Any Idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current solution is fine, in my opinion. The underscore naming-convention used on view-partials doesn't apply for modules, that's why you got the uninitialized constant-error. If you name it `ApplicationHelper::ApplicationContainer` it has to be in a file named `application_container.rb`

What you have in your code now is a module you can include in other Helper-modules– just as you would a partial in your views.